# write file in memory with java.nio?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

With nio it is possible to map an existing file in memory. But is it possible to create it only in memory without file on the hard drive ?

I want to mimic the CreateFileMapping windows functions which allow you to write in memory.

Is there an equivalent system in Java ?

The goal is to write in memory in order for another program ( c ) to read it.

Comment: Why don't you just create a byte buffer and write to that?

Comment: You can tell Windows to create a memory mapping of the pagefile rather than a named file. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Are you talking about inter-process communication?

Comment: Indeed, the goal is to write in memory in order for another program ( c ) to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following.  A file is created but this might be as close as your going to get.

```
MappedByteBuffer
MappedByteBuffer.load()
FileChannel
FileChannel.map()
```

Here is a snippet to try and get you started.

```
    filePipe = new File(tempDirectory, namedPipe.getName() + ".pipe");
    try {
        int pipeSize = 4096;
        randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(filePipe, "rw");
        fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
        mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, pipeSize);
        mappedByteBuffer.load();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    ...
```

Comment: This work and indeed, everything is in RAM (i check with some utilities, no hdd i/o)

But, do you know how to retrieve the mapped file with c code ? using window function ?

Comment: @Foobyto - No I don't.  Worth adding a new question to get it answered.

Comment: Actually, after research, you can't write in RAM with java, you need to do it through the system api. 

This thing for exemple: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537

Java just let you to put a file in RAM in order to modify it faster, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Most libraries in Java deal with [input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and [output streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) as opposed to [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) objects.
Examples: [image reading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29), [XML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#createXMLStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream%29), [audio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioFileFormat%28java.io.InputStream%29), [zip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html#ZipInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29)

Where possible, when dealing with I/O, use streams.

This may not be what you want, however, if you need random access to the data.

When using memory mapped files, and you get a [MappedByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) from a [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) using [FileChannel.map()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29), if you don't need a file just use a [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) instead, which exists totally in memory.  Create one of these using [ByteBuffer.allocate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocate%28int%29) or [ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect%28int%29).