# Execute a bytestream as a process in Java without writing to file

Tags: java

Basically, I want to be able execute a byte stream as a file, without writing said bytes to a file.

I want to do this in a windows environment.

You could say I want a to create a file, copy the stream to the file, and open the file as an executable, but I want the file to have no physical manifestation on the disk.

Thanks

Comment: On what OS do you want to do that ?

Comment: EDIT: in a windows environment.

Comment: Is the content of the stream a native executable or a Java class that you'd run on the JVM? If it's the latter, you could load it with a `ClassLoader`.

Comment: @Jesper - It's the former (any .exe file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible to do using the standard Java API. You will have to rely on some OS specific native implementations, either that do the whole thing for you, or that allow you to create some sort of RAM-disk on which you can place your temporary data and execute it.

Possibly related:

- [write file in memory with java.nio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827481/write-file-in-memory-with-java-nio)

Comment: This RAM-disk seems interesting and just might be what I need... any information on how do it in Windows?

Comment: Google for *ramdisk windows*. You'll find lots of free software. Read up on how to control one through the command line. Use `ProcessBuilder` to create the ram-disk, write the bytestream to the ram-disk, use `ProcessBuilder` again to execute the bytestream from the ram-disk.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you bytestream is the one of a standard exe, and you don't want to call a whole virtualisation environnement, the short answer is no because internal adresses in the code wouldn't map.

Here's a more detailled answer :

[process.start() embedded exe without extracting to file first c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997594/process-start-embedded-exe-without-extracting-to-file-first-c-sharp)